# why different classes can equilavent to each other and can read same property value

Tags: objective-c, xcode

For example in this case;

```
@interface Anotherclass : Base
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * surname;

@end

@interface SomeInfo : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * name;
@end

SomeInfo *sInfo = [userInfo objectForKey:Notification_anotherclassobject];
```

why `sInfo.name` properly casts/ works? is there an explanation?

Comment: Because under the hood it calls `getName:`, and both implements a method called that ("different" ones, but both have one). But clearly, it's hard to tell because your example is not explicitly saying that `[userInfo objectForKey:Notification_anotherclassobject];` returns a `Anotherclass` instance...

Comment: yes it returns that, but implicitly

Comment: For more digging on how works method, you could look for `objc_msgSend` and associate methods. But in higher level, you could just do too: `if ([aSomeInfoInstance respondsToSelect(getName:)]` &`if ([anAnotherClassObjectInstancerespondsToSelect(getName:)]`, they should both returns true.

Comment: i think thats objc specific i dont remember anywhere in java,swift,ts can do cast like this